# Changing certain values in every row of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Let's say I have a matrix like this -

```
A = 1 2 3 4;
    5 6 7 8
```

I want to change certain values in every row but I want to keep some of them, for example I want to make first element in every row `0` and second element `1`. However, I want to keep the rest as they were originally. Result would be like  this -

```
A = 0 1 3 4; 
    0 1 7 8
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner

```
A(:,1:2) = repmat([0 1],[size(A,1) 1])
```

**Edit 1:** Additionally, if you want to change the last column to some number say `9`, then use this -

```
A(:,[1:2 end]) = repmat([0 1 9],[size(A,1) 1])
```

**Edit 2:**
If you would like to extend it more number of columns, you might as well create an array of column indices and another array for the new values. This code might help you understand -

```
column_array = [1 2 6 7 8];
new_values_for_columns = [ 0 1 2 3 4];
A(:,column_array) = repmat(new_values_for_columns,[size(A,1) 1])
```

Comment: This is great since I have like 100 numbers to change. May I ask one more question there are values that I dont want to change in between for example I want to change first two and the last one. How do I do that.

Comment: @user3460203 Check out Edit 1.

Comment: Actually I got many numbers at the end to be more clear I want to change lets say first 100 than the numbers between 150-200.

Comment: @user3460203 What's your matrix size? You can get that info with the command - `whos matrix_name`. And what should be the new values?

Comment: My matrix size is pretty large. I got 4000 something rows and 150 colomns and as I said I want to change certain vales in between and I checked out again and I have to change 3 seperate places.

Comment: By `3 separate places`, do you mean ` 3 separate columns`?

Comment: @user3460203 If you would like to set all the values in first column as `0`, second column as `1` and the last column as `9`, use the edited code. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Lets say I have A= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 I want to change first two colomns with 0 1  and 6-8 colomns with 2 3 4 end result will be like                                                               A = 0 1 3 4 5 2 3 4 9; 0 1 12 13 14 2 3 4 18

Comment: @user3460203 Check out Edit -2.

Comment: @user3460203 Make sure it runs with your actual large dataset. Consider accepting the answer once it works. Read more about accepting answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you want to change every row of a given column (ie. A(:,column) = newValue)

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]
A(:,1) = 0; A(:,2) = 1;

>> A

A =

 0     1     3     4
 0     1     7     8
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change certain values in every row you can use `A(row,:) = newValue;`

In your example, you should use `A(1,:) = 0;` and `A(2,:) = 1;`